# How to solve a binomial expression up to and including $x^2$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm doing a binomial expansion that uses $(1+ax)^2$ form and I was wondering how to solve the bottom expression up to and including the term $x^2$

$$\frac{19x -3}{(1+2x)(3-4x) }$$

would I rearrange $(19x-3)(1+2x)^{-1} 3^{-1}\left(1-\frac{4x}{3}\right)^{-1}$ and just expand it all out and multiply them together?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the last term be $\left(1-\frac{4x}3\right)^{-1}$?

Comment: @saulspatz oh yeah complety forgot to add that -1 thanku

Comment: And the $x$ is omitted, too.  But the answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It is often convenient to start with a *[partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Illustration)*
\begin{align*}
\frac{19x-3}{(1+2x)(3-4x)}=-\frac{5}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+2x}+\frac{9}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3-4x}
\end{align*}
and continue with a *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.